# What is the required Risk/ Reward ratio in Forex?

Tags: fx

It is usually taught in forex training courses that the risk:reward ratio should be 1:2.
My question is: why is it 1:2 but not other ratio?

Also, I am new to forex trading. To what level of technical analysis (TA) should I know in order to be able to trade? My friend told me that: you just need basic TA (some basic indicators), it is more about understanding the psychology of the crowd (thus human) and how determined and discipline you are. Is he true?

Comment: Hi SiXUIm. Welcome to Quant SE. As you might see in the [faq], this site is dedicated to quantitative finance professionals and academics. "Beginner" (no offence) FX trading advises are off-topic here. Maybe some of these sites have forums or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding risk reward ratio, there is no magic about the number 2. However, demanding a ratio of 2 does make practical sense. We may look at it in two-folds:

**From behavioural finance point of view**, investors generally demand more (2 dollars) profits for certain amount (one dollar) of loss. This skewed heuristic of decision making has been explained well in Daniel's [Prospect Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prospect_theory), which is dictated as investor's common tendency of Loss Aversion.

**From portfolio management point of view**, reward/risk of 2 loosely implies Sharpe ratio of two, which is a widely followed standard to determine the superiority of a tradable strategy. Sharpe ratio of less than that in simulation is hardly to achieve consistency and low draw down in live trading, given all the pitfalls of backtesting and trader's incapability to carry forward trading during stressful draw down period. Ernie Chan also once argued about this view in his article [The importance of 2](http://epchan.blogspot.sg/2012/11/the-importance-of-2-as-sharpe-ratio.html).

Your next question of forex trading deserves a separate post by itself. My quick answer would be:

1. Technical analysis is worth learning. It gives a tool for market timing. However, it is not sufficient for you to achieve profitability on trading.
2. News is almost useless. They are often already priced and never new. Believe me or not, professionals rarely make decisions based on news. However, processing of large amount of news quickly offers an edge, as information diffusion is not immediate.
3. In trading, you need to have an edge. If you don't have one, then create one before starting.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you see this epic [return](http://www.ariva.de/euro-dollar-kurs/chart?layout=neu&boerse_id=36&t=week) here? Thats forex news. What do you think is an "edge"?

Comment: Hi emcor, sorry, but I have to disagree with you respectfully. News is useful if it's really new. However, except for some institutional players, retail investors cannot act on news quickly, rendering it almost useless. I've mentioned that, if  you can utilize the news before its absorption by the market, then of course you can make a living trading that edge. I'm a quant trader, and so far I cannot achieve that, and so does some of my senior friends. I'm just telling you what I've experienced, and it can well be wrong.

Comment: For the portfolio management point of view, it appears that 2 is the smallest threshold. Are there any papers or empirical evidence prove this?
Regarding the second question, I agree with you. Also, it's so tempting to trade based on news due to big fluctuation, but I realize it's not much different from gambling (I've tried some times and mostly lost money)

Comment: There is no magic or prove for the importance of 2. It is there more for a practical reason. High Sharpe ratio (~2 or above) in hindsight gives you more margin of safety should the live trading deviates from your simulation.